# awk: error : tent of \{\}

Tags: awk, regular-expression, email

I use the following regex to find email addresses:

```
echo "name@server.com" | awk '/^([a-zA-Z0-9_-.\+]+)@([a-zA-Z0-9_-.]+).([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/ {print $0}'
```

But it returns the error:

```
 awk: cmd. line:1: error : tent of \{\}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short version, use this:

```
$ echo "name@server.com" | 
>    gawk '/^([-a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+)@([-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/'
```

---

Assuming the actual error message is something like:

```
awk: cmd. line:1: error: Invalid range end: …
```

Then, there are 4 issues in your line:

1. The dash (`-`) means "character range" not an explicit dash.

   The reason for the error message is that the two characters surrounding the dash (`-`) inside the character range (`_` and `.`) are not in (ASCII) order. The character range `.-_` raise no error. But I am certain that you do not mean to say "character range" (all characters between a dot `.` and an underscore `_`), but to match an explicit dash (`-`).

   To match an explicit dash inside a "bracket expression" you need to make it the first or the last character of the range. Either `[-…]`, `[…-]`. Or, discouraged, escape it `\-`. That is, both of these work:

   ```
   [-a-zA-Z0-9_.+]
    [a-zA-Z0-9_.+-]
   ```

   But no, a backslash is **not** a general solution to make a dash explicit. Try:

   ```
   $ echo 'ab-cd' | grep -Eo '[a\-c]+'
   ab
   c
   ```

   The grep regex (even if extended: `-E`) does not match the dash.
2. The `+` is not special inside a "bracket expression", thus, it needs no escaping (and escaping inside "bracket expressions" is a bad habit). Use this:

   ```
   ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+)@
   ```
3. A dot `.` is an special character that "match any character except newline".
   As such, you need to either escape it `\.` or use a "bracket expression" `[.]` to explicitly match a dot character, use this:

   ```
   ^([-a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+)@([-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)\.
   ```
4. And, finally, the "interval expression" is an extension over historical awk implementations, it may not work in all awk's. This is usually "not a problem", but if it is, you will need to use:

   ```
   ([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z]?[a-zA-Z]?[a-zA-Z]?)$
   ```

But you are probably using GNU awk, and the correct syntax should then be:

```
$ echo "name@server.com" | 
>    gawk '/^([-a-zA-Z0-9_.+]+)@([-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/'
```

Answer (score 2):

**Answer:**

```
echo "name@server.com" | awk '/^([-a-zA-Z0-9_.\+]+)@([-a-zA-Z0-9_.]+).([a-zA-Z]{2,5})$/ {print $0}'
name@server.com
```

**Explanation:**
The character `-` is ambiguous in the position where you put it, since it could represent an interval. Moving it to the beginning of the regexp, or escaping it, works just fine.

**Further info:**
Check your regexes on this useful [website](https://regex101.com/) when in doubt.

---

As correctly pointed out by [Isaac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/265604/isaac), the last dot in the expression does not do what you probably think it does: `.` represents any character, and you should escape it if you want it to mean a literal dot `\.`

Further optimizations include not escaping characters inside brackets since it is unnecessary. I'm pointing to `\+` in the first character set, and I have to thank [Isaac](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/265604/isaac) again for spotting this!

One more thing that is beyond me is why you would use all those round brackets `()`.

Apart from correcting the use of `-` and suggesting a few minor improvements, the underlying theme here is the vastly discussed opportunity of employing regular expressions to validate email addresses. Correctly matching any email address is a tough task that requires a far more complex expression than one would initially imagine. A reasonable take, often found on this and similar forums is to use the simplest regex that is expectedly going to work with your dataset.

Comment: Note that the website that you link to does not provide a way of testing standard POSIX regular expressions, as far as I can see.

Comment: The dot (`.`) should be escaped. The plus (`+`) needs no escaping.

Comment: @Kusalananda [Use this link](https://regex101.com/r/1q3faH/1). It is not very good, but at least both BRE and ERE are named there.

Comment: @Kusalananda good point, I'm spoiled by PCRE and would recommend using tools that support them.

Answer (score 1):

The hyphen `-` is special character in character class ([Bracket Expression](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03_05)) which specifying the character range. If you want add literal `-` into your character class you will need to either escape it or move it to the end or beginning (after the `^`, if any) of your character class.

```
[a-z-]
[-a-z]
[a-z\-A-Z]
```

> 7.[...]
>
> The < hyphen-minus > character shall be treated as itself if it occurs
>   first (after an initial `^`, if any) or last in the list, or as an
>   ending range point in a range expression. As examples, the expressions
>   `[-ac]` and `[ac-]` are equivalent and match any of the characters
>   'a', 'c', or '-'; `[^-ac]` and `[^ac-]` are equivalent and match any
>   characters except 'a', 'c', or '-'; [...]
>
> If a bracket expression specifies both '-' and ']', the ']' shall be
>   placed first (after the '^', if any) and the '-' last within the
>   bracket expression.

Comment: It is not a good idea to escape characters inside "bracket expressions" as that will not work in most other extended regexes.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of `awk` are you using?

This command does not error when I use GNU `awk`, although it produces no output.

Using `solaris` `awk` it produces this error:

```
awk: syntax error near line 1
awk: bailing out near line 1
```

Reading through your `regex`, it's never going to match an email address...

Comment: I use GNU Awk 4.1.3 under ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: "Reading through your regex, it's never going to match an email address..." : Yes, I put the correct regex. Please see the new edition.